# Getting the value inside an element in an xml file using LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have a simple character creation style form where the user can enter their name into a textbox and it will be stored in a string called "playername". After the player has entered their name they can then press the save button which will bring up a SaveFileDialog where the playername string is saved into an XML file using XElement. If the user than exits the game and starts it up again they can press the load button and the value thats inside the XML value for name should overwrite the current name. I can't seem to find anything on grabbing the value from inside an XML document and overwritting a string using LINQ. Thanks in advance.

```
<Character>
  <Basicinfo>
    <Name>bob</Name>
  </Basicinfo>
</Character>
```

code:

```
string playername;

private void savebutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SaveFileDialog savefiledisplay = new SaveFileDialog();
        savefiledisplay.FileName = "temp";
        savefiledisplay.Filter = "XML File|*.xml";
        savefiledisplay.Title = "Save your game file";
        savefiledisplay.DefaultExt = "xml";

        if (savefiledisplay.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            XElement savefile = new XElement("Character",
                new XElement("Basicinfo",
                    new XElement("Name", playername)));
            savefile.Save(savefiledisplay.FileName);
        }
    }

private void loadbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        OpenFileDialog openfiledisplay = new OpenFileDialog(); //creates an open file dialog
        openfiledisplay.DefaultExt = "xml"; // default extension to look for
        openfiledisplay.Title = "Open your save file"; //title of the open file display
        openfiledisplay.Filter = "XML File|*.xml"; //filters for only xml files

        if (openfiledisplay.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {
            XElement loadsavefile = XElement.Load(openfiledisplay.FileName);
            //code for setting the playername string equal to the value inside the xml file
        }
    }
```

Comment: Surely you can find plenty of documentation and examples if you search Linq To XML.

Comment: I have not found a single one on getting a value from inside an element and setting it to a string.

Comment: [Here is one sample](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/c%23/2773/linq-to-xml/9340/read-xml-using-linq-to-xml#t=201704161318074652241). If you post your xml I'm sure someone will write the exact code for you if they can do so before the question is marked duplicate.

Comment: Thank you, it completely slipped my mind to post the xml my bad.

Comment: something like `var Name = loadsavefile.Descendants("Name").Value;`

Comment: @Slai I think you forgot a `FirstOrDefault()` on there :)

Comment: bah .. I was thinking of the VB XML Descendant Axis Property. `var name = savefiledisplay.Element("Basicinfo").Element("Name").Value;`

Comment: @Slai Thank you, it works perfectly! :)